# Ruby on rails debugger gem times out in developement mode

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running into a strange problem lately which did not occur before in my Rails 3.2.12 application.  I use the debugger gem extensively to debug my application and usually I never had this problem while debugging in the development environment.

I put a breakpoint in my code by inserting a debugger statement where I want the debugger to break.  This works correctly. I can examine the variables and step over a few statements nicely.  However, when I say 'cont' which is short for continue to let the program run to the next breakpoint or display the results of computation, I am getting the timeout error as shown below:

Timeout::Error: execution expired:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Timeout::Error: execution expired:

This never happened to me in the development mode until recently.  I am not sure where the problem is.  I don't mind setting the timeout to a high number in development mode so that I can debug my application without having to restart it frequently.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Bharat

Comment: do you see something like this in your gem file --> gem "rack-timeout" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
# config/initializers/timeout.rb <-- create this file
Rack::Timeout.timeout = 120  # seconds
```

Comment: Hello Jiten, thanks for your response.  this works.  I had another file by the same name under config directory, i.e., config/timeout.rb.  I have adjusted the timeout in both.  Which one overrides the other?